# Issue in display business places custom google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, csv, google-search-api

Hello friends i want to display my business places in my custom google map in my application so i used my maps for that ands i uploded two my  places wtih csv file and drop pin on that and i used for search place , for search api of google see my below code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TextWatcher {


final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
static GoogleMap myMap;
static double lat;
static double lng;
static String address;
static String title;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; 
Context mContext;
SearchAddess mSearchAddess;

LinearLayout mLinearLayout_search_input;


ImageButton mButtonFind;
ImageButton mButtonSearch;
ImageButton mButtonDistance;
ImageButton mImageButtonDistanceFromTo;
ImageButton mImageButtonMultipleMarker;
LinearLayout mLinearLayoutFromTo;

EditText mEditTextFrom;


Button mButtonGo;


AddressLookup mAddressLookup;



RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
static Marker startPerc;
Marker marker;

EditText mAutoCompleteTextViewAddress;
String getsearchingAddress;



String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;
String[] mKmName=null;
String [] mStringsDialogOption=null;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
LatLng mLatLng;

public static double CurrentLatitude;
public static double CurrentLongitude; 
GPSTracker gps;
Spinner mSpinner;
Spinner mSpinnerKm;
double mDoubleKm=0.0;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

Button mButtonFindPlace;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );
    mContext = this;
    mIntent=new Intent();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectDiskReads()
    .detectDiskWrites()
    .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());




    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    mLinearLayout_search_input = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_search_input_ll);
    mSpinnerKm=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spr_km);
    mButtonSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mButtonSearch);
    mButtonFind = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_cancel);
    mButtonFindPlace=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_find_palce);
    mSpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);
    mButtonDistance=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mButtonDistance);
    mImageButtonDistanceFromTo=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mButtonDistanceFromTo);
    mImageButtonMultipleMarker=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mButtonMultipleMarker);
    mEditTextFrom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFrom);
    mButtonGo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
    mRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_search_input_rl);
    mAutoCompleteTextViewAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autocompleteview_address);

     gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled     
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            CurrentLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
            CurrentLongitude = gps.getLongitude();


        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    // Array of place types
            mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

            // Array of place type names
            mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

            mKmName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.km_name);

            mStringsDialogOption = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dialog_option);

            // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
            // to populate the spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mKmName);
            mSpinnerKm.setAdapter(adapter1);

            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            mButtonFindPlace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   


                    int selectedPosition = mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];
                    String type1 = mKmName[mSpinnerKm.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                    String ss[]=type1.split(" ");
                    String s=ss[0];
                    mDoubleKm=1000 * Double.valueOf(s);                 

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+CurrentLatitude+","+CurrentLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius="+String.valueOf(mDoubleKm));
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyDst4th70R2y2kaExv10UIr7cxS3KQUejs");


                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());


                }
            });

    initMap();

}

/** A class, to download Google Places */
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.wait) ,getString(R.string.searching_place));
    }
    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrlNearByPlace(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
        ParserNearByTask parserTask = new ParserNearByTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }

}
/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrlNearByPlace(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);                

            System.out.println("URL "+strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();                

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}   

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserNearByTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            

        if(mProgressDialog!=null)
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        // Clears all the existing markers 
        myMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){


            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
            System.out.println("Get name "+ hmPlace.get("place_name"));

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker. 
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            myMap.addMarker(markerOptions);     

            myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(CurrentLatitude, CurrentLongitude), 12));

        }       

    }

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.cd:

        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled     
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            CurrentLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
            CurrentLongitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        initMap();
    case R.id.normal:
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        return true;
    case R.id.satelite:
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        return true;
    case R.id.hybride:
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        return true;
    case R.id.tarrin:
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void hideKeyBoard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAutoCompleteTextViewAddress.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void initMap() 
{

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

    if (myMap != null)
    {

        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);         
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Null Value");
    }

    if(myMap!=null)
    {

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        getAddressFromLatLong(CurrentLatitude, CurrentLongitude);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
    }   




    mButtonFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            mButtonSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mLinearLayout_search_input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getLatLongFromAddress(mAutoCompleteTextViewAddress.getText().toString().trim());
            hideKeyBoard();


        }
    });


}
// Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.wait) ,getString(R.string.route_draw));

        }
        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            if(mProgressDialog!=null)
            {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();  
            }
            if (myMap!=null) 
            {
                ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
                PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Traversing through all the routes
                for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                        HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                        points.add(position);                       
                    }

                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                    lineOptions.width(2);
                    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

                }

                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                myMap.addPolyline(lineOptions); 
            }

        }           
    }   

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";         

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


    return url;
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    getLatLongFromAddress(mAutoCompleteTextViewAddress.getText().toString().trim());
}
public static void getLatLongFromAddress(String youraddress)
{

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +youraddress+"&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

        lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");
        address=((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");



        System.out.println("Lat "+lat);
        System.out.println("Lng "+lng);
        System.out.println("address"+address);

        startPerc = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
        .title(address));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 12.0f));

     } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public String getAddressFromLatLong(double currentLatitude,
        double currentLongitude)
{
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +currentLatitude+","+currentLongitude+"&sensor=false");

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try 
        {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

            lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lng");

            lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lat");
            address=((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");

            startPerc = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title(address).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
            myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 12.0f));

            System.out.println("Lat "+lat);
            System.out.println("Lng "+lng);
            System.out.println("address "+address);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return address;

}
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
    {
        //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        //                  "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        //                  .show();
    }

    else 
    {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                RQS_GooglePlayServices);


    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

when i run above code it is not showing my business place which i add form my csv file so any idea how can i display in my application ?

Comment: You can just export your maps as KML (https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en) and then import your KML as a layer to Google Maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Comment: Verma : how can i access my place in my application ?